# How can I tidy this data set step by step?

Tags: r, dataset, tidyr

I am a data analysis beginner, currently learning how to use R in DataCamp. I am looking to tidy a data set called irsi which can be found in R Studio. I was wondering that how I can clean this data set step by step as following:

Original:

```
head(iris)
   Species     Sepal.Length Sepal.Width  Petal.Length Petal.Width
1  setosa          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2
2  setosa          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2
3  setosa          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2
4  setosa          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2
5  setosa          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2
6  setosa          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4
```

Step 1:

```
> head(iris.wide)
  Species Part   Length Width
1  setosa Petal    1.4   0.2
2  setosa Petal    1.4   0.2
3  setosa Petal    1.3   0.2
4  setosa Petal    1.5   0.2
5  setosa Petal    1.4   0.2
6  setosa Petal    1.7   0.4
```

Step 2:

```
head(iris.tidy)
  Species Part  Measure Value
1  setosa Sepal  Length   5.1
2  setosa Sepal  Length   4.9
3  setosa Sepal  Length   4.7
4  setosa Sepal  Length   4.6
5  setosa Sepal  Length   5.0
6  setosa Sepal  Length   5.4
```

Please feel free to let me know if there is something I didn't mention clearly.
Any suggestion would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: it is case of reshaping from wide to long.  Try `library(data.table);melt(setDT(iris), measure = patterns("Length", "Width"), value.name = c("Length", "Width"))` and do some changes

Answer (score 5):

This is a `tidyverse` solution:

```
head(iris) %>%
    unite(Sepal, Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width) %>%
    unite(Petal, Petal.Length, Petal.Width) %>%
    gather(Part, Value, 1:2) %>%
    separate(Value, into = c("Length", "Width"), sep = "_") %>% # <-- Step 1
    gather(Measure, Value, 3:4)                                 # <-- Step 2
```

or faster:

```
head(iris) %>% 
    gather(key, value, 1:4) %>% 
    separate(key, into = c("Part", "Measure"))
```

Since you're learning how to manipulate/tidy data, I strongly recommend doing this step-by-step, to understand what each of the manipulations are doing.